# Using Scrapy to scrape data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, pip

I am trying to scrape data using scrapy. But having trouble in editing the code.  Here is what I have done as an experiment:

```
import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['http://anon.example.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('h2'):
            yield {'Agent-name': title.css('a ::text').extract_first()}

        next_page = response.css('li.col-md-3 ln-t > div.cs-team team-grid > figure > a ::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

I have used the example from website scrapy.org and try to modify it. What this code is doing is extracting the names of all the agents from the given page.
But I want that scrapy should go inside the page of the agent and extract its information from there.
Say for example:

```
Name: name of the agent
Phone: Phone Number
Email: email address
website: URL of website .. etc
```

Hope this clarifies my problem. I would like to have a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['http://anon.example.com']


    # get 502 url of name
    def parse(self, response):
        info_urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="text"]//a/@href').extract()
        for info_url in info_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=info_url, callback=self.parse_inof)
    # visit each url and get info
    def parse_inof(self, response):
        info = {}
        info['name'] = response.xpath('//h2/text()').extract_first()
        info['phone'] = response.xpath('//text()[contains(.,"Phone:")]').extract_first()
        info['email'] = response.xpath('//*[@class="cs-user-info"]/li[1]/text()').extract_first()
        info['website'] = response.xpath('//*[@class="cs-user-info"]/li[2]/a/text()').extract_first()
        print(info)
```

The `name` can be found in the detail page, so in first step, we just collect all the detail url.

Then we visit all the url and get all the info.

The date may need clean-up, but the idea is clear.

Comment: is it possible to write it in csv file?

Comment: @Jaffer Wilson change print to `yield info` and use command line `scrapy crawl spider_name -o out.csv`. `-o` means output file. please read scrapy document for detail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you please tell me how you are defining the depth of scraping? As I see there are URL of website pages and the program is only scrolling the URL and not going to the website. This is good . Can you explain me please?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: @Jaffer Wilson you can control the request of url by using `scrapy.Request`, each you pass url to it, it will visit the page.

Comment: The script is failing when the agent have fax number, it is not extracting the email and website URL. PLease check